# Is there a program that will teach me how to play a piece of music coded in a MIDI file?

Tags: keyboard, midi

I recently broke my keyboard that did this perfectly. I now have a computer with a bunch of MIDI files (*.MID) and need a program that will show me the partition and maybe play it with me.

I'd also love for it to be a program that waited for me to play each note on my USB keyboard so that I can learn the songs.

Comment: That really tends to be a 'Keyboard' learning function; I know the Yamahas can do that, probably others too, but it's not something I've ever seen on a software player. Wish you luck in your hunt.

Comment: Probably need a different keyboard, but this looks relatively useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PqhJZ6_m8S8

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could look for software that imports MIDI files and automatically transcribes them to sheet music.

This is quite common for guitar, like Guitar Pro which also has a sheet music display.
You might try:

http://midisheetmusic.sourceforge.net/ or
http://musescore.org/

This approach, of course, implies a more traditional way of learning than you're used to.

Answer (score 0):

In Sibelius, you can open MIDI file, ask to show the keyboard view and while replaying, the keyboard view shows keys being pressed and the sheet view highlights the notes being played. Even free demo version can do this (nothing can be saved, however).

MuseScore seems lacking the keyboard view but definitely can convert MIDI file into sheet music, and while playing, will highlight the currently sounding notes. You can use all features of MuseSCore it for free.

I think this can be used for self learning.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Synthesia (or a Linux variation - Lynthesia). It will do exactly what you want, will allow you to select a midi file, practice the notes, then practice the rythm, then practice altogether rythm+notes in a final melody. Each step of practice might be separated by hands (practice left-hand only or right-hand only). It can hide some instruments and show notes only for others, or it can mute and hide those instruments and you can play the rest.
Note that in free edition it can only play music for you and show notes falling from top down. It'll cost you money (not much, given that they have sale right now) to buy the features you need, but that's worth it. Have a look at Youtubes videos on how does synthesia works.